# Create an alarm based on a CloudWatch insight query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

**My problem:**

I would like to blacklist IPs which are accessing my public AWS API Gateway endpoint more than 5 times a hour.

**My proposed solution:**

- Requests are logged to CloudWatch
- Requests are counted and grouped by IP
- An alarm monitors IPs send a message to a SNS topic in case the threshold is met
- Lambda is triggered by the message and blacklists the IP

[image]

I am able to log and count the IPs by using the Insight query below:

```
fields ip
  | stats count() as ipCount by ip
  | filter ispresent(ip)
  | sort ipCount desc
```

[image]

What I am struggling to accomplish is getting an CloudWatch Alarm based on this query.

I have searched a lot but no success. Any ideas on how to create such a metric / alert?

Comment: Can you try with this approach "put IP/count in dynamoBD and run another lambda to trigger SNS every 5 minutes if match condition"?

Comment: It's a good idea but would cost me a lot of money...

Comment: How big is your IP/Count data? million rows or thousand rows

Comment: @FranxiHidro Are you planning to run the insights query every X minutes or something similar?

Comment: I just want to restrict users to access it more than 5x / hour keeping the API Public

Comment: @KaustubhKhavnekar Yes, that is my idea, a cronjob to check if count >5, then (do something) block that IP. KagueiNakueka, you may need a WAF for your public API to do that feature, and I think my solution is cheaper.

Answer (score 3):

I know you planned to do a custom Lambda, but check if WAF already fulfills your use case. For example, the rate limit section in this article here clearly allows you to define the rate per 5-minutes for a given IP:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/classic-web-acl-rules-creating.html

If you are not doing anything else, a custom Lambda function may not be needed.

### EDIT

If you want to go down the path of CloudWatch alarms, I think you can define a **metric filter** to create a **CloudWatch metric**. Then you can create the alarm based on the metric.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/MonitoringLogData.html

Answer (score 0):

The best approche is to use the managed services "AWS WAF" which is perfectly integrated with your APIs.

The problem with a custom solution, is the latency, time to aggregate logs, count, and the cost, because each time a lambda will run with queries....

In API Gateway you can attach a WAF Web ACL directly,  you can indicate the rate per 5 min, per 10min... for you need, is the job of the WAF.